# How do I properly resize this navigation text?

Tags: html, css

Bear with me but I'm a total HTML/CSS nooby, couldn't find anything on here that asked this SPECIFIC question. I want to align these ul tags to completely to the right side as they get scaled, but If I scale it any more it'll be too big when the window is scaled-down but just right for the max window and vice versa when the window is smallest. Which is what I have right now. (we're only looking at width here). For example:

```css
* {

    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}


#mainnav{
    padding-left: 45%;
    margin-right: 8vmax;
    display: block;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    top: 0; 
}

nav ul{

    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
}


body{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practice</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    
    <script src = '/Users/apple/Downloads/Javascript/practice.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

    <header> 
        <nav id='mainnav'>
            <ul> <a src='www.google.com'> Home </a></ul>
            <ul>Contact</ul>
            <ul>Pricing</ul>
            <ul>Help</ul>
        </nav>

    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

What it looks like now:

**Scaled to the max:-**

[image]

**Scaled to smallest:-**

[image]

Comment: Hey @BuddyPal just add  `justify-content: flex-end`   in #mainnav selector in your css file.. It should work fine..

Comment: fastest fix yet, THANK YOU

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just give your width to 100%

```
#mainnav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0 3rem;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    top: 0; 
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your HTML in the `<nav>` element is a little wonky. In terms of semantics, you should never use a [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) for a single plain text item. If you have more than one item to be put in a list, it should be done using an unordered `<ul>` or ordered list `<ol>` with nested list elements `<li>`.

> For an unordered list, the permitted content is zero or more `<li>`, `<script>` and `<template>` elements.

I updated the HTML by replacing the `<ul>`'s that didn't have any `<li>` elements and adding child `<li>` elements to the parent `<ul>` with nested `<a>` elements for each menu item link. Next, you should be using the `href` attribute for `<a>` tags and not `src` which would be invalid.

In terms of updating the styling to match your picture, you should remove the `padding` and `margin-right` on `#mainnav`. Now you can just make it a [Flex Box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) by adding `display: flex` to the `#mainnav` container. Finally, aligning the flex items along the main axis (ie horizontally) you can simply use [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) with value `flex-end` which positions the flex items at the end of the row.

```css
#mainnav{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding: 0 3rem;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    top: 0; 
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    position: sticky;
}

nav ul li a {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

body{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practice</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    
    <script src = '/Users/apple/Downloads/Javascript/practice.js'></script>

</head>
<body>

    <header> 
        <nav id='mainnav'>
            <ul> 
              <li><a href='www.google.com'>Home</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href='/'>Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @BuddyPal Did this help solve your problem?